# How can I use activation-group while calling kie api container?

Tags: drools, jbpm, rule-engine, kie, kie-workbench

I have been tring to use activation-group  but I don't have any idea how to call activation-group from Api rest ? Please help me how to add activation-group inside of the request below.

```
package com.myteam.arduinodevre2;

//from row number: 1
rule "Row 1 Rulduino"
activation-group "gold"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        f1 : ArduinoEntity( switchOn == true , voltaj >= 1000 , voltaj < 2000 )
    then
        modify( f1 ) {
                setLightOn( true )
        }
end

//from row number: 2
rule "Row 2 Rulduino"
activation-group "gold"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        f1 : ArduinoEntity( switchOn == true , voltaj >= 5000.0 , voltaj < 10000.0 )
    then
        modify( f1 ) {
                setLightOn( false )
        }
end

//from row number: 3
rule "Row 3 Rulduino"
activation-group "gold"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        f1 : ArduinoEntity( switchOn == false )
    then
        modify( f1 ) {
                setLightOn( false )
        }
end

//from row number: 4
rule "Row 4 Rulduino"
activation-group "silver"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        f1 : ArduinoEntity( switchOn == true , voltaj >= 1.0 , voltaj < 3.0 )
    then
        modify( f1 ) {
                setLightOn( false )
        }
end
```

```
{

  "commands": [
    {
      "insert": {
        "object": {
          "com.myteam.arduinodevre2.ArduinoEntity": {
            "switchOn": true,
            "voltaj": 1100

          }
        },
        "out-identifier": "ArduinoEntity",
        "return-object": true
      }
    },
    {
      "fire-all-rules": "" ,
            "fire-targetgroup": "silver"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I fire  my target activation-group by using this kinnd of thing ->"fire-all-rules": "silver"  But I cound not find valuable answer by googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get ActivationGroup from the KieSession, not from the KieContainer. You need to create a KieSession from the KieContainer and then use **kieSession.getAgenda().getActivationGroup("").setfocus()** method to get the ActivationGroup. You can check this [link](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/nexus/content/shadows/unzip/org/kie/kie-internal/6.4.0.CR1/kie-internal-6.4.0.CR1-javadoc.jar-unzip/org/kie/internal/definition/rule/InternalRule.html) to check about the method return type and other methods related to it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call an activation group. What you might be referring to is an agenda group. You can set focus on an agenda group and all rules with that agenda group will be eligible for firing.

You can go further and add the activation-group to your rules, which will then cause only one rule in that group to fire.

In order to "call" agenda group from the REST API, you need to set focus like this:

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "set-focus": "myAgendaGroup"
    },
    {
      "insert": {
        "object": {
          "com.myteam.arduinodevre2.ArduinoEntity": {
            "switchOn": true,
            "voltaj": 1100
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "fire-all-rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```